# If an AJAX request is "pure content" then where are the other parameters coming from?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.6

I'm no expert, but when I make an AJAX call, I'm expecting to receive (server side) the exact content I put into the `data` parameter of the AJAX call.

This is exactly what I see in chrome dev console > network.

So server side, I'm struggling to access this data. 
Firstly, a `gettype()` tells me I'm receiving an object, but it looks like an array.

Secondly, if I convert it to an array, all other rubbish gets added in.

A simple `Log::info($AJAXRequest)` shows me an array has been received.

```
[2018-08-24 02:14:15] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'xyz',
    array (
      0 => 
      ... etc.
```

After `$arr = (array) $AJAXrequest;` a simple `Log::info($arr);` shows I have an array with all sort of other rubbish added in at the front.

```
[2018-08-24 02:14:15] local.INFO: array (
  '' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'json' => 
  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::__set_state(array(
     'parameters' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'category' => 'xyz',
        array (
          0 => 
        ... etc.
```

Where does this extra content come from? I just tried to convert what I thought was an object, to an array.

**AJAX call in Javascript:**

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"/surveys",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: {
        'CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){alert("Success");},
      failure: function(errMsg) {alert("Fail");}        
    });
    }
```

**RESOURCE CONTROLLER**

```
...
 public function store(Request $AJAXrequest)
...
  if($AJAXrequest->ajax()){
            $arr = (array) $AJAXrequest;
            Log::info(gettype($AJAXrequest));
            Log::info(gettype($arr));
 .....
```

Comment: Please post your controller. I think what you're seeing is the Request object; logging that on its own won't be too helpful.

Comment: I don;t understand... it's sourced from an AJAX call in some Javascript - thre's no controller involved. See edit above.

Comment: You've used the tag "laravel-5.6" and in your log you have "Symfony\Component..." so I presumed you are calling a laravel route from your ajax? - What does your route "/surveys" point to, in your laravel?

Comment: It's a resource controller `Route::resources(['evaluations' => 'EvaluationsController']);`

Comment: Your `$AJAXrequest` variable is an instance of [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html). I'm not exactly sure what you're asking though. What would you expect to see from logging such an object?

Comment: I don't understand why my `$AJAXRequest` is an instance of `Request`. That's the whole point. I thought when I was dealing with AJAX, I'm using something totally different to a HTTP Request like $_POST. I thought AJAX was something that delivered to the server, *exactly* - without alteration or interference - what was sent. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Your code quite literally has `Request $AJAXrequest` so it could be nothing else. An AJAX request is still a plain HTTP request using POST, GET, PUT, etc. The only difference is that it is generated via JavaScript. That's it, nothing more

Comment: (bangs head on desk quietly). Sorry, I've come back to this code after a whie a way didn't even notice. I don't know how else to receive the ajax data. Unless, I should not be using a resource controller to do so, but rather a seperate class....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to work backwards to help with your misunderstanding...

Laravel's `Illuminate\Log\Logger` class runs all log messages through an internal method [`formatMessage()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php#L220) which includes

```
if ($message instanceof Arrayable) {
    return var_export($message->toArray(), true);
}
```

Now, [`Request`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) implements `Arrayable` so it satisfies this condition, calling the [`toArray()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L610) method

```
/**
 * Get all of the input and files for the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray()
{
    return $this->all();
}
```

That's why you see what you do for `Log::info($AJAXrequest)`

---

Now, if you're just after the de-serialized JSON, that should be found in

```
$AJAXRequest->json()
```

which returns a `ParameterBag` instance.

If you're after the JSON string as posted, use

```
$AJAXrequest->getContent()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, (and putting up with some shortsighted questions) - much appreciated.